# Problem with weight painting strong pencil

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I can't create a soft move of mesh with armatures because when i paint with low strength (0.001) it's like it's (1,000).
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong. 
(sorry but english is no my native language and I can't explain better)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use a factor of 0.001, it's completely useless, you can't paint anything with such a low value. Do you want this part to remain blue (no influence) or to turn red (maximum influence)? To turn it blue you have to use the Substract option instead of the Add one, but it's in contradiction with the bone structure, so I guess you want to turn this part red. To do so, stay in Add mode and increase the value up to 0.5 or 1. Also, make sure that the structure of your mesh fits the structure of your bone, right now your mesh seems weird, I don't know if it's on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It Can solve by adding corrective smooth modifier to your mesh but if you are creating for unity game then it will not work in unity. And i am also having same problem if you get the answer the please reply to me because i have the same problem.good luck