# low strenght when weight painting

Tags: rigging

I can't create a soft move of mesh with armatures because when i paint with low strength (0.001) it's like it's (1,000). Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong. (sorry but english is no my native language and I can't explain better)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108815/problem-with-weight-painting-strong-pencil

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. If you are not getting answers edit your original post to add more information. Read: [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)